# How do you condense list of check boxes?

Tags: sharepoint-online, multi-select, checklist

I have a web part that contains about 40+ check boxes. As you can probably understand, it requires a lot of scrolling to view all the selections. Is it possible to make, say, 4 columns of 10 selections to condense the page a bit?

I know  you can make a custom list and then multi-select from a lookup but then I run into a problem during spreadsheet export where each selection is preceded by a '#' and a number.

Answer (score 1):

Can you create an InfoPath form to collect the data you need? You can make your form the default edit view for you list so that any time a list item is edited, the form is used.